# How to change Quora profile URL

Tags: url, quora

I have created an account with 'Example Name' (just for example) and I saw the url of my profile is showing something like this: https://www.quora.com/Example-Name-8 (This is just for example and not associated with anyone).

My question is how can I change my profile url ('Example-Name-8' with some customize name)? Is it possible I can create url according to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not change your profile url - The only way to do that is to change your name (which has to be your legit name).

The only reason you see that number after your name on the URL is because someone else may have the same name or that's just the way Quora creates there URLs.

If you want to get more in depth please see the quora forum on this question here:

[Is it possible to change my Quora profile URL?](http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-change-my-Quora-profile-URL)

Comment: Quora (as a web application) questions are fine here, actually.